# Must bread dough clear the side of the mixer using the hook?

Tags: bread, stand-mixer

I can get it to clear just fine with the paddle, but I can't reliably do so with the hook attachment, even after ten minutes at the fastest setting. My flour is fairly strong, autolysed, and the hydration is ~70%. I find myself adding way too much flour to have it clear the bowl.

Answer (score 5):

Often, higher hydration doughs don't need to be mixed in a mixer at all.  However, when using a mixer, it is more important to get the hydration correct, than to have all of the dough come away from the side of the bowl.  I would say to use a kitchen scale to measure ingredients, and don't worry about whether or not the dough comes away from the side of the mixing bowl.

Comment: I agree weighing is a helpful starting point but getting a feel for the dough is still essential. A good feel for dough compensates for all variables. Weighing compensates for only flour compaction but the relative humidity is not accounted for and can play a significant role.